# Best way to change div width on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, effect

How did the creator of this portfolio website make that cool image effect?
http://www.adhamdannaway.com/

Im currently training my self to learn the more advanced stuff but im having trouble with this effect.

The way i did it is make a container with a width of 1280px (1280px is width of img). Made 2 images one with color and other black and white. 2 divs width a width of 50% and float left, float fight. the right one didnt appear right so ive used this: background-position: top right and it worked. They centered perfect even on bigger screen sizes. But the problem lies here. How can i make it so when i hover the left div the div gets width 100%. and the same for the other div.

I know i can do it with #div:hover and then width 100% and the fixed that the image gets above with z-index but thats only happening when im hovering but not when ive dehovered. Obvious becouse its on :hover. But i currently have no clue how to do this on a better/right way.

Ive put the code on jsfiddle.net/aLyde6pa/ but it doesnt work for some reason.

Ive probably explained more than i should but i hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance!

ps: English is not my main language. :)

Comment: I would suggest that you rephrase your question, as you are asking for an opinion and Stack Overflow is not the place for that. Please read more on [What types of question should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with CSS you can do something similar with "Transition" but not as animated as in the example because you are limitated with CSS what to change on hover.
As I know you can't change elements before the element you hover over ( correct me if I'm wrong )

Here is a simple example ( https://jsfiddle.net/9510a6kj/ ) :

**HTML**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right{
    float:left;
}

.left{
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: width 1s ;
}

.right{
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.left:hover{
    width: 300px;
}

.left:hover + .right{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Maybe this helps

Transiton will "animate" ( more delay ) the change from width A to B

Cheers

Comment: YOU sir are my hero. Thanks man this really helped. Had to change this a little tho :D

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well its always great to learn more skills but you can add a hover effect without even using JS, by using the CSS hover effect.

Generally looks something like:

```
    #img1 {  
    width: 50px;  
    height: 50px;      
    }   

    #img1:hover {   
    width: 75px;       
    height: 75px;    
    }
```

Kind of the lazy or hacky way of doing it but it works fine, and its a lot easier at a very early stage of learning development.
     You could also use a jquery pluggin like this one (just change the text out for an image and edit the properties)

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover
http://www.geekality.net/2010/08/26/jquery-nice-and-smooth-hover-effect/

Comment: Just to clarify: you are suggesting him to use the regular `.hover` event function from jQuery, which is not an external plug-in to the library.

Comment: I'd say the built in jQuery hover effect design wise looks the same as the CSS :Hover.  but If you wanted to get fancier with it theres alot of really cool different libraries and jQuery pluggins out there that will look more attractive.  like this one:   http://www.geekality.net/2010/08/26/jquery-nice-and-smooth-hover-effect/       PS.  Sorry for all the edits, getting used to posting on stackoverflow, and I keep hitting return